# grouch and mud - sesame street

Tags: meaning, idioms

Watching a parody on Sesame Street, episode 'True Mud (A True Blood Parody)',  I got confused.
Bill comes in a cafe and says that he wants mud. Other customers think he is a grouch, because he loves mud.
Why do they think so? Why must a grouch  love MUD? A grouch is an ill-tempered person. I can't understand. Is it an idiom?

Comment: if it is a parody of a fiction, set in a different fiction, it is possible that the only logic is internal to the parody itself. However, assuming that the parallel is 'someone must be a vampire if they want blood', then it may also be riffing on such references as Mud-bloods in Harry Potter and  grouchy people eating worms http://bussongs.com/songs/nobody-likes-me-worms.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Sesame Street, Oscar the Grouch famously loves trash and all things dirty. His pet Slimey is in a group called *Earth, Rain and Mud*, [which performs a song about sounding out the word mud](http://oscarthegrouch.wikia.com/wiki/Earth,_Rain_and_Mud).

Comment: @Andorian It's been on since the early 1970's, so that might take a while ...

Comment: I'm ready, I have enough time )